# jQuery Expander + Fancybox hiding images

Tags: jquery, fancybox, expander, fancybox-2

I'm using the jquery.expander.js plugin along with fancybox to display summaries of news articles with images, but after activating fancybox by clicking on an image, the original image is hidden.

I've setup an example here: http://tria.com/test.htm

Any idea how to fix this? I've tried to make fancybox stop replacing the image with a placeholder, but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the attributes `class="fancybox"` and  `rel="group"` to the anchor `<a>` tag, not to the `<img />` tag. That will solve the issue.